# php pagination using class

Tags: php

hello everyone plz help me out with this script.
I am calling my pages in this way in main page

```
if(isset($_GET['page'])=='view_user' && $_GET['page']=='view_user')include("user/crud_user.php");
```

i have user class in which i am doing pagination

```
$self   =   $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        if($this->openPage<=0) {
            $next   =   2;
        }

        else {
            $next   =   $this->openPage+1;
        }
        $prev   =   $this->openPage-1;
        $last   =   $this->pages;

        if($this->openPage > 1) {
            echo "<a href=$self?page=1>First</a>&nbsp&nbsp;";
            echo "<a href=$self?page=$prev>Prev</a>&nbsp&nbsp;";
        }
```

The url of the page which is using this class is lie this

```
admin.php?page=view_user
```

Now i can get pagination no according to the records but when i click on no it rather take me to admin.php?page=3 because of self . I want to stick to that page for showing the result . I tried in this way also `$self="admin.php?page=view_user";`but no luck . please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use one variable for serving two different purposes is quite unusual idea.
Let me suggest you to use 2 different variables, one to designate included page and another to point to the actual page in pagination.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

do

```
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'view_user')
{
    include("user/crud_user.php");
    exit;
}
```

because of many reasons.

for pagination try the following: http://www.catchmyfame.com/2007/07/28/finally-the-simple-pagination-class/

Comment: who said you cannot? bool can be compared to string all right

Comment: it makes your answer pointless, if you still unable to catch that, loller

Comment: your answer is pointless. `isset($_GET['page']) == 'view_user'` will evaluate to true as well. So, although being nonsense, it works and it cannot be cause.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel, we all know that true is not equal to a string, regardless of PHP's poor programming interface.

Comment: -1 **You are completely wrong** and Col. Shrapnel is right. Why don't you actually test your assertions before you insult others? `true == 'view_user'` will always evaluate to `true`, and `isset($_GET['page']) == 'view_user'` will **not** always evaluate to `false`. If `$_GET['page']` is set, the expression will always evaluate to `true`. The net effect is that it functions as intended.

Comment: I am not talking of programming interfaces but of certain statement. And it evaluates to true

Comment: @Robert Rather than giving up, why not edit your answer so it's not full of incorrect information?

Comment: it's still just a side note and being not answer.